# Pushing a box out of view

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to experiment with my CSS code and want to know how to push a box out of view. Let me go into more detail...

I have lined up two boxes side by side using the grid element and would like box one to push box two out of the left margin so it is not visible. (I will be bringing it back into view later with animation). So at the starting point only box one is visible.

Does anyone know how to make this possible without adjusting the widths?

(I could do it by simply adjusting the width of box one but I am looking for different methods.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code of the question, it is hard to answer, but let me try.

To hide element you could use `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` or `opacity: 0;`

You could also say to the parent element that it has `position: relative;`
and to the element that you want to hide, `position: absolute; left: 150%;` or `right: -50%;`, depending on which element you would like to hide, left or right respectively.  and with javascript or css animation change later its left or right property in order to show it.

There are a lot of ways for you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I could change the opacity of box two and then have the opacity shift on both of them so when one fades out the other fades in.

Comment: I also did not think of raising the left over 100% (I actually did not know that wad possible lol).

Comment: StackOverflow is made for people to learn and help each other! Thanx for the upvote!

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure if I am understanding your question but in css you can use `display: none;` to hide a block. You can then use `display: block;` to bring it back into view.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted it to slide into view and push box one out of frame when doing so. But than you for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am also not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you could try it with:

```
    margin-left: -23px
```

and on the outer element

```
    overflow:hidden
```

Comment: I understand I can set widths and make the overflow hidden, but I was trying to do it without making any adjustments to the widths. (That way I can make it easier when I do my media queries and transfer it to smaller screen). But thank you for answering my question.